# Error Message when I show Image from Datagrid view to Picture box in C# and also when i check my image in datagrid view

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, picturebox

I continuously get an error when I show an image from Data grid view to Picture box in C# and also when I check my image in data grid view. I am struggling with this from last 3 days but doesn't succeed so it is request

---

***Here is my Code:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
namespace MeterConnectionSystem
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=UMERMUGHAL;Initial Catalog=PattikaMeterConnections;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //void BindData()
        //{
        //    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=UMERMUGHAL;Initial Catalog=PattikaMeterConnections;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

        //    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM EmployeeData", con);
        //    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        //    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //    sda.Fill(dt);
        //    dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;


        //}

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofdlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if ((ofdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK))
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofdlg.FileName);
                }

            }
            //ofdlg.Title = "Open Image";
            //ofdlg.Filter = "Image Files(*.JPG;*.PNG;*.GIF) | *.JPG;*.PNG;*.GIF ";
            //if (ofdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            //{
            //    // pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofdlg.FileName);
            //    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofdlg.FileName);
                    
            //}
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
            byte[] arr;
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
            //var imageconverter = converter.ConvertTo(pimg, typeof(byte[]));
            //MemoryStream mmst = new MemoryStream();
            //pictureBox1.Image.Save(mmst, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
            //byte[] img = mmst.ToArray();
            //dataGridView3.Rows.Add(img);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into EmployeeData values (@AgPersonalNumber, @Cnic, @DOB,@Name,@FatherName,@Post,@BPS,@Address,@TownVillage,@BloodGroup,@MobileNumber,@PresentWorking,@JobStatus,@SubOffice,@image)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgPersonalNumber", int.Parse(agpersonaltextbox.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cnic", cnictextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(dobtextbox.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nametextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", fathernametextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", posttextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BPS", bpscombobox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addresstextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TownVillage", townvillagetextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloodGroup", bloodgroupcombobox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", mobilenumbertextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PresentWorking", presentworkingtextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobStatus", jobstatuscombobox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubOffice", subofficetextbox.Text);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imageconverter);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", arr);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", img);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Insert Successfully");
                //BindData();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM EmployeeData", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd2.ExecuteReader());
                dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;





                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Not Insert " + ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }



            agpersonaltextbox.Clear();
            cnictextbox.Clear();
            //dobtextbox.Clear();
            nametextbox.Clear();
            fathernametextbox.Clear();
            posttextbox.Clear();
            //bpscombobox.Clear();
            addresstextbox.Clear();
            townvillagetextbox.Clear();
            //bloodgroupcombobox.Clear();
            mobilenumbertextbox.Clear();
            presentworkingtextbox.Clear();
            //jobstatuscombobox.Clear();
            subofficetextbox.Clear();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            //textBox18.Clear();
            //textBox19.Clear();
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM EmployeeData", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd2.ExecuteReader());
            dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
            byte[] arr;
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

            try
            {

                con.Open();
                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update EmployeeData set AgPersonalNumber ='" + int.Parse(agpersonaltextbox.Text) + "', Cnic ='" + cnictextbox.Text + "', DOB='" + DateTime.Parse(dobtextbox.Text) + "', Name='" + nametextbox.Text + "',FatherName='" + fathernametextbox.Text + "',Post='" + posttextbox.Text + "',BPS='" + bpscombobox.Text + "',Address= '" + addresstextbox.Text + "',TownVillage='" + townvillagetextbox.Text + "',BloodGroup= '" + bloodgroupcombobox.Text + "',MobileNumber='" + mobilenumbertextbox.Text + "',PresentWorking='" + presentworkingtextbox.Text + "',JobStatus='" + jobstatuscombobox.Text + "',SubOffice='" + subofficetextbox.Text + "',Image='" + arr + "' where AgPersonalNumber ='" + int.Parse(agpersonaltextbox.Text) + "' ", con);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update EmployeeData set  Cnic ='" + cnictextbox.Text + "', DOB='" + DateTime.Parse(dobtextbox.Text) + "', Name='" + nametextbox.Text + "',FatherName='" + fathernametextbox.Text + "',Post='" + posttextbox.Text + "',BPS='" + bpscombobox.Text + "',Address= '" + addresstextbox.Text + "',TownVillage='" + townvillagetextbox.Text + "',BloodGroup= '" + bloodgroupcombobox.Text + "',MobileNumber='" + mobilenumbertextbox.Text + "',PresentWorking='" + presentworkingtextbox.Text + "',JobStatus='" + jobstatuscombobox.Text + "',SubOffice='" + subofficetextbox.Text + "',Image='" + arr + "' where AgPersonalNumber ='" + int.Parse(agpersonaltextbox.Text) + "' ", con);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully");
                //BindData();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM EmployeeData", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd2.ExecuteReader());
                dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Not Updated " + ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
        }


        private void dataGridView3_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            agpersonaltextbox.Clear();
            cnictextbox.Clear();
            //dobtextbox.Clear();
            nametextbox.Clear();
            fathernametextbox.Clear();
            posttextbox.Clear();
            //bpscombobox.Clear();
            addresstextbox.Clear();
            townvillagetextbox.Clear();
            //bloodgroupcombobox.Clear();
            mobilenumbertextbox.Clear();
            presentworkingtextbox.Clear();
            //jobstatuscombobox.Clear();
            subofficetextbox.Clear();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;

            if (dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                agpersonaltextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                cnictextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dobtextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                nametextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                fathernametextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                posttextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                bpscombobox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                addresstextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                townvillagetextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                bloodgroupcombobox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                mobilenumbertextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                presentworkingtextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                jobstatuscombobox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                subofficetextbox.Text = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
                
                
                byte[] imgdata = (byte[])dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgdata);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

                
              

                //System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream((byte[])dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value);
                //pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                //pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
                //ms.Position = 0;

            }
        }

       

        
    }
}
```

[image: The Error Message that I Recieved]

[image: The Code i am getting when i move slider in datagrid view to check image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to find out the solution, actually the problem is only with Northwind database images, so better to use the following code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write("your photoArray", 78, "your photoArray".Length - 78);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

put your byte[] array in "your photoArray" blocks.